# How to use Gammaray on Android

Tags: android, qt, qt5, qmake

I've used the Qt debugging tool Gammaray quite a bit on Linux. Now I want to use it also on Android but fail to make it work.

I've followed the instructions outlined here:
https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/blob/master/Install.txt

The make install step completes successfully.

```
...
[ 92%] Built target gammaray_widgetinspector_plugin
[ 95%] Built target gammaray_qmlsupport
[100%] Built target gammaray_styleinspector_plugin
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libgammaray_kitemmodels-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libgammaray_common-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libgammaray_core-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libgammaray_probe-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/styles/gammaray_injector_style-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_codecbrowser_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_fontbrowser_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_modelinspector-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_quickinspector-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_signalmonitor-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_statemachineviewer_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_mimetypes-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_network-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_translatorinspector-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_guisupport-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_textdocumentinspector-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_actioninspector_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_widgetinspector_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libgammaray_widget_export_actions-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_sceneinspector_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_styleinspector_plugin-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_qmlsupport-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_quickwidgetsupport-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_bluetooth-qt5_8-arm.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/lib/libplugins_gammaray_gammaray_positioning-qt5_8-arm.so
```

Now I've created a simple qmake test project and added
android: QT += GammaRayProbe to it as outlined in the documentation.

When I now run qmake I always get:
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: GammaRayProbe

From poking around in the mkspec files of my Qt5.8 install I wonder how this is supposed to work. The make install step doesn't install a .pri file that would allow QT += GammaRayProbe to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Install.md was outdated at that point in time. It has been updated to be correct.

Two additional things to keep in mind.
- you need to build a full GammaRay in addition to the Android probe.
- make sure to add the various plugins of GammaRa to your .apk.